# Why are we having argv[2][0]

Tags: c, arrays

I came across a program in C, where it once used `argv[1]` and `argv[3]`, and once `argv[2][0]`. The issue is not I'm not able to differentiate between 1-dimensional arrays and 2-dimensional arrays, the issue here is the use of `argv[2][0]`. What would the argument look like with such dimensions? Why wasn't `argv[2]` used instead?

Thanks.

Comment: That is no 2D array, but the entry of the second index is a character from the string pointed to by the first index' entry.

Comment: May be, the program was only interested in the first char of 2nd argument (i.e. `argv[2][0]`)? What's the context? Post the relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv[2]` is a pointer to the whole argument while `argv[2][0]` is just the first character of the argument.

Answer (score 2):

argv is a *char[] so basically an array of strings. argv[2][0] will get the first character of the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

`argv[2][0]` is the first character of the third string (the second argument).